# Eloquent scope method gives different results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`

#### Working code

```
$cityWithEvents = City::with(['events' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereDate('start_time', Carbon::today('America/Montreal'))->orwhereBetween('start_time', [Carbon::today('America/Montreal'), Carbon::tomorrow('America/Montreal')->addHours(4)]);
        }])->where('active', 1)->get()->keyBy('id');
```

#### Not working code

```
$cityWithEvents = City::with('todayEventsWithAfterHoursIncluded')
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->get()
            ->keyBy('id');
```

#### City model

```
public function events() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Event', 'App\Venue');
    }

    public function todayEventsWithAfterHoursIncluded () {
        return $this->events()
            ->whereDate('start_time', Carbon::today('America/Montreal'))
            ->orwhereBetween('start_time', [
                Carbon::today('America/Montreal'),
                Carbon::tomorrow('America/Montreal')->addHours(4)
            ]);
    }
```

#### Questions

When trying to create a `scope` method the query gives me different result. I can't see why and what should I change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used `scopes` a few times, but never within a `->with()` clause. On your `City` model, create a new `scope`:

```
public function scopeTodayEventsWithAfterHoursIncluded($query){
  return $query->with(["events" => function($subQuery){
    $subQuery->whereDate('start_time', Carbon::today('America/Montreal'))->orWhereBetween('start_time', [Carbon::today('America/Montreal'), Carbon::tomorrow('America/Montreal')->addHours(4)]);
  });
}
```

Then, on your `City` query, add it as a `scope` function:

```
$cityWithEvents = City->where('active', 1)
->todayEventsWithAfterHoursIncluded()
->get();
```

I think the way you are using it requires that your `Event` model has the scope on it, as you're technically calling `with("events")` on your base query and your scoped one.

Let me know if this changes you results.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the query, you should do it like this:

```
$cityWithEvents = City::withTodayEventsWithAfterHoursIncluded()
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->get()
            ->keyBy('id');
```

You scope in you model should look like this:

```
public function scopeWithTodayEventsWithAfterHoursIncluded ($query)
{
    return $query
        ->with(['events' => function ($q) {$q
            ->whereDate('start_time', Carbon::today('America/Montreal'))
            ->orwhereBetween('start_time', [
                Carbon::today('America/Montreal'),
                Carbon::tomorrow('America/Montreal')->addHours(4)
             ]);
        }]);
}
```

Now it should be equal.